# Apache htaccess redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, 301-redirect

I have a client who has a domain like `this-site.com` and also `thissite.com`
Without going into the entire issue behind it, we need to redirect any incoming request to any `*.this-site.com` to the matching `*.thissite.com`.

So for example:

```
subdomain1.this-site.com -> subdomain1.thissite.com
subdomain2.this-site.com -> subdomain2.thissite.com
subdomain3.this-site.com -> subdomain3.thissite.com
```

Is there a way to preserve the first part of the URL and pass it on to the second domain?

Comment: Are there too many subdomains to hardcode them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all these subdomains resolve to the same place on the filesystem then... to redirect from `this-site.com` to `thisstite.com` whilst preserving the *subdomain* and remainder of the URL (ie. URL-path and query string), you can do something like the following, using mod_rewrite, near the top of your `.htaccess` file in the root of your site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.this-site\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.thissite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

I've assumed `HTTPS`. This redirects `https://<subdomain>.this-site.com/<url-path>[?<query-string>]` to `https://<subdomain>.thissite.com/<url-path>?<query-string>`.

The `%1` is a backreference to the first captured group in the last matched *CondPattern*. In other words, this matches the *subdomain* (`([^.]+)` part in the preceding regex) in the requested hostname.

Note also:

- This will redirect all subdomains, including `www`.
- But it won't redirect sub-subdomains, eg. `subsubdomain.subdomain1.thissite.com` will not be redirected.
- And it will only redirect subdomains, so it won't redirect `this-site.com`.

This is also a temporary (302) redirect. If this is intended to be permanent then change the 302 to 301, but only after you have confirmed it is working OK. (301s are cached hard by the browser so can make testing problematic.)